# General syntax error raised from CONNECT BY query in Informix when using quoted table identifiers

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, informix, connect-by

When running the following query on an Informix database, the database reports a general syntax error (without any indication with respect to what causes the problem). The same query runs perfectly on CUBRID or Oracle databases, both of which also support the `CONNECT BY` syntax:

```sql
select 
  lower(connect_by_root "t_directory"."name"), 
  connect_by_isleaf, 
  connect_by_iscycle, 
  substr(
    sys_connect_by_path(lower("t_directory"."name"), '/'), 
    2) "dir"
from "t_directory"
start with "t_directory"."parent_id" is null
connect by nocycle prior "t_directory"."id" = "t_directory"."parent_id"
order siblings by lower("t_directory"."name") asc
```

The database I'm using is a Developer Edition of Informix 12.10 on Windows. I'm running the query from a JDBC driver with the following connection URL (to allow for quoted table identifiers):

```
jdbc:informix-sqli://localhost:9092/test:INFORMIXSERVER=ol_informix;DELIMIDENT=y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact issue here is the fact that `prior` doesn't accept quoted table identifiers, although quoted column identifiers seem to be fine. This query runs perfectly well:

```sql
select 
  lower(connect_by_root "t_directory"."name"), 
  connect_by_isleaf, 
  connect_by_iscycle, 
  substr(
    sys_connect_by_path(lower("t_directory"."name"), '/'), 
    2) "dir"
from "t_directory"
start with "t_directory"."parent_id" is null
connect by nocycle prior t_directory."id" = "t_directory"."parent_id"
order siblings by lower("t_directory"."name") asc
```

... with the difference being:

```sql
-- Bad:
connect by nocycle prior "t_directory"."id" = "t_directory"."parent_id"

-- Good:
connect by nocycle prior t_directory."id" = "t_directory"."parent_id"
```